# Multiple EqualTo Strings in Conditional Formatting IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, openoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I am using Open Office Calc on Windows

When using **Format > Conditional Formatting** and selecting Formula is drop down under *Condition 1*, I am typing my formula

```
IF($B10="BMW")
```

This works great.

However I have more strings I have to search for.

I tried

```
IF($B10="BMW","Mercedes","Fiat","Ford")
```

however this does not work.

I could tick **Condition 2**, and type

```
IF($B10="Mercedes")
```

and then the same for **Condition 3** and so on, but this way seems wasteful and also you onyl have three total Conditional boxes... So its not enough anyway.

Isnt there a cleaner way to do this?

Something like separating Strings with commas like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OR`:

`IF(OR($B10="BMW";$B10="Mercedes";$B10="Fiat";$B10="Ford"))`

And you can also exclude `IF`:

`OR($B10="BMW";$B10="Mercedes";$B10="Fiat";$B10="Ford")`

Depending on your regional settings you may need to use commas (`,`) instead of semicolons.

Comment: This does not work, I have tried both your suggestions. Thanks for the effort

Comment: "This does not work" - this doesn't really help to improve my answer. What is the result? what happens is you insert it in a cell?

Comment: Sorry, but When Using Conditional Formatting you select a result if the condition is met, For my case I change the cell background color. When using your above code the cell background color does not change. However If I try **IF(OR($B10="BMW"))** the BG color does change, just not when using multiple strings

Comment: However the following does appear to work **OR($B10="BMW") OR($B10="Mercedes") OR($B10="Fiat") OR($B10="Ford")**

Comment: Hey Mate, it appears your syntax is wrong, instead of commas putting semicolons works

**OR($B10="BMW"; $B10="Mercedes"; $B10="Fiat"; $B10="Ford")**

If you want to edit ur post and update I will mark as correct

Comment: Glad it works. I've updated my answer.